# How can I determine where, in a very nested SQL statement I can convert a number variable to a decimal with 2 decimal places?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a VERY nested SQL statement, I want to produce a decimal value with only 2 digits behind the decimal point.  Here are 2 paragraphs from a large SQL program below. The statement I am having trouble with is this one:  ROUND(((convert(decimal(11, 6), sum(pf1.NO_OF_RECONCILED_TRX)) / tot_tab.tot_trx) * 100.0),2) AS "% To Total Acct".  I need the values in the "% To Total Acct" column to be as 58.82 instead of 58.820000000000000000.

Image of results is also attached

[image: 1]

```
SELECT                                              
a1.ACCOUNT_NUMBER                                           
    , a1.ACCOUNT_NAME                                           
    , ap1.PASS_ID                                           
    , isnull(ap1.PASS_NAME, 'Out') "Pass Name"                                          
----, (convert(decimal(23, 6), sum(pf1.NO_OF_RECONCILED_TRX)) / tot_tab.tot_trx) * 100.0 "% To Total Acct"                                              
, ROUND(((convert(decimal(11, 6), sum(pf1.NO_OF_RECONCILED_TRX)) / tot_tab.tot_trx) * 100.0),2) AS "% To Total Acct"                                            
----, (convert(decimal(23, 6), sum(pf1.NO_OF_RECONCILED_TRX)) / tot_tab.tot_trx) "# Reconciled Items by Pass"                                           
----, SUM (NO_OF_RECONCILED_TRX) as TotalRows                                           
    , SUM (NO_OF_RECONCILED_TRX) as "# Reconciled Items by Pass"                                            
                            
FROM
   BRR_ACCOUNT_HIERARCHIES ah1
   inner join BRR_ACCOUNTS a1 on ah1.ACCOUNT_ID = a1.ACCOUNT_ID
   inner join BRD_PROPERTY prop on a1.ACCOUNT_ID = prop.ACCOUNT_ID and prop.USER_ID = 1952 and        prop.PROPERTY_NAME = 'Allow Access' and prop.PROPERTY_VALUE = 'Yes'
   inner join BRR_PASS_FACT pf1 on ah1.ACCOUNT_ID = pf1.ACCOUNT_ID
   inner join BRD_DAY d1 on pf1.DAY_ID = d1.DAY_ID AND d1.DAY_ID > 15614 and d1.DAY_ID < 15695    --SEPT 30 & DEC 20TH
   left outer join BRR_AUTOREC_PASSES ap1 on pf1.PASS_ID = ap1.PASS_ID
   cross join
(...
```

RESULTS:

```
ACCOUNT_NUMBER  ACCOUNT_NAME    PASS_ID Pass Name   % To Total Acct # Reconciled Items by "PASS NAME"
11003   11003 CASH IN TRANSIT-BRANCHES  57  GL (FAST) CO ACCT CENTER FULLREF    58.82000000000000000    24108
11003   11003 CASH IN TRANSIT-BRANCHES  37  GL 1-1 (AR) CO ACCT CENTER REF-NO(Full) 41.15000000000000000    16864
11003   11003 CASH IN TRANSIT-BRANCHES  697 GL 1-1 Co Acct Center Ext Ref not blank o or CIW    0.01000000000000000 6
11003   11003 CASH IN TRANSIT-BRANCHES  58  GL(1-1) AR CO-ACCT-CTR-SRC (CCMWO RESOLVE)  0.01000000000000000 6``
```

The commented-out the lines I tried using.  The closest I came to what I need was from using the ROUND statement. It replaced the trailing numbers with trailing zeroes with the exception of the first 2 numbers behind the decimal point. I eliminated the numbers, but they were replaced by zeroes. For example, I need for the value to be as 58.82 instead of 58.8200000000000.

Comment: But numerically 58.82 is the same number as 58.8200000000000? Why do you care? And just `convert(decimal(9,2),YourValue)` if its important.

Answer (score 0):

As Dale K mentioned, just change

```
ROUND(((convert(decimal(11, 6), sum(pf1.NO_OF_RECONCILED_TRX)) / tot_tab.tot_trx) * 100.0),2) AS "% To Total Acct"
```

to

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(11,2),ROUND(((convert(decimal(11, 6), sum(pf1.NO_OF_RECONCILED_TRX)) / tot_tab.tot_trx) * 100.0),2)) AS "% To Total Acct"
```